# Using Postgres with Grails

Tags: postgresql, grails

Has anyone gotten Grails working with Postgres? I have used this [tutorial](http://hartsock.blogspot.com/2008/07/postgresql-and-grails.html) and everything seems to make sense and be correct to me. However when I 'grails run-app' I get this error

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgres://10.0.0.21/tribes'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

My DataSource file is

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='com.opensymphony.oscache.hibernate.OSCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgres://10.0.0.21:5432/tribes"
            username = "grails"
            password = "grails"
        }   
    }   
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgres://10.0.0.21:5432/tribes"
            username = "grails"
            password = "grails"
        }   
    }   
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgres://10.0.0.21:5432/tribes"
            username = "grails"
            password = "grails"
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: yes. I have tried several versions anyway but am pretty sure I have the right one

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://www.fankhausers.com/postgresql/jdbc/#nosuitabledriver):  "[if] you get a runtime error that says 'No suitable driver found', it is likely that the URL passed to DriverManager.getConnection is malformed or otherwise incorrect".  So what's wrong with yours?  Well, the examples in the tutorial look like this:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/grails
```

Yours looks like this:

```
jdbc:postgres://10.0.0.21:5432/tribes
```

I'm guessing those missing two letters are causing your trouble.

Answer (score 19):

In the BuildConfig.groovy file uncomment the external maven *repositories*  and then add this line

**runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'** in the *dependencies* section

Comment: This line is essential to getting Grails talking to Postgresql. But you don't need to uncomment any external Maven repos if you have already copied the Postgresql JDBC jar to your project/lib directory. Also, you need to create the database that you reference in your JDBC url before you do grails run-app.

Comment: Updating this since it's been awhile since the answer, and the version of the postgresql driver has been upgraded.  The current driver (as of Jan 2014) is:

`runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc4'`

This is for JDK 1.6.  You'll need to change that last 'jdbc4' to 'jdbc3' if you're still running JDK 1.5.  For more info see http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html